# What is payload-type tag means in jingle IQ?

Tags: java, android-studio, xmpp, ejabberd

When initializing jingle call we should send an IQ as shown below. I still don't understand the use of payload-type and which criteria to take into account in order to list them. I tried to read [Supported media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats) from android documentation but I did not see any relation with payload-type. After I read [RTP payload formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_payload_formats), I some what understood what was a payload.
I want to know if it is possible to list available payload types in my device or I should add other dependenies in my project in order to list them.

```
<iq from='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
    id='ph37a419'
    to='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony'
    type='set'>
  <jingle xmlns='urn:xmpp:jingle:1'
          action='session-initiate'
          initiator='romeo@montague.lit/orchard'
          sid='a73sjjvkla37jfea'>
    <content creator='initiator' name='voice'>
      <description xmlns='urn:xmpp:jingle:apps:rtp:1' media='audio'>
        <payload-type id='96' name='speex' clockrate='16000'/>
        <payload-type id='97' name='speex' clockrate='8000'/>
        <payload-type id='18' name='G729'/>
        <payload-type id='0' name='PCMU' />
        <payload-type id='103' name='L16' clockrate='16000' channels='2'/>
        <payload-type id='98' name='x-ISAC' clockrate='8000'/>
      </description>
    </content>
  </jingle>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMPP [XEP-0167: Jingle RTP Sessions: Application Format](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0167.html#format) speciications would be better place to look I guess:

> The application format consists of one or more encodings contained within a wrapper `<description/>` element qualified by the `'urn:xmpp:jingle:apps:rtp:1'` namespace (see Namespace Versioning regarding the possibility of incrementing the version number). In the language of RFC 4566 each encoding is a payload-type; therefore, each `<payload-type/>` element specifies an encoding that can be used for the RTP stream, as illustrated in the following example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Those codecs does not depend on android right? or the user sender (endpoint) must put audio/video in the supplied codecs before he sends it? (I am newbie in networks)

Comment: You specify what you can handle - you are limited by the libraries and their capabilities.